# Django If statement String Comparison

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

code.code_type has a string value **"mel"**
and it outputs the same value in the webpage.
when i just run {{code.code_type}}
But when I compare it in if statement with a string
{% if code.code_type == "mel" %} 
Nothing is happening.

```
{% for code in codes%}
 {% if code.code_type == "mel" %}
   <div class="snippet">
     <div class="snippet-container">
       <div class="snippet-heading">
           <a href="#">{{code.code_type}}</a>
        </div>
        <div class="snippet-code">
             {{code.code_snippet}}
         </div>
         <div class="snippet-note">
             {{code.code_note}} 
         </div>
       </div>
     </div>
  {% endif %}
{%endfor%}
```

Comment: Please share the relevant models you are rendering here.

Comment: What does `type(code.code_type)` return? Does it return `<class 'str'>`?